# ASP MVC - auto parse json string form variable to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model, http-post

I have a standard html form POST request with one parameter.

**Form Data:**

```
model:{"Id":"2901179e-553e-4c9c-8c5c-281822ff2d11","Name":"T1","Sessions":[{"Id":"","Type":5,"Version":null,"Name":"","BestLapPoints":null,"TimeOfDayMins":1080,"hours":18,"minutes":0,"MaxLaps":null,"DurationMins":null,"Description":"","Points":[]},{"Id":"","Type":7,"Version":null,"Name":"","BestLapPoints":null,"TimeOfDayMins":1200,"hours":20,"minutes":0,"MaxLaps":null,"DurationMins":null,"Description":"","Points":[{"Position":1,"Points":10},{"Position":2,"Points":8},{"Position":3,"Points":6},{"Position":4,"Points":5},{"Position":5,"Points":4},{"Position":6,"Points":3},{"Position":7,"Points":2},{"Position":8,"Points":1}]}]}
```

It's a json serialized object that maps to an MVC Model class.

I'd like to configure the Controller Action taking the model as parameter to automatically deserialize the json string from the form 'model' variable to the specific Model class

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(DomainModel model)
    {
    }
```

I'd also like to avoid writing a custom Model Binder for that model, instead have something generic that would work for any similar scenario.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Stevo

Comment: That should happen automatically, as long as the request `Content-Type` is correctly set.

Comment: It doesn't, even if I override the Request Content-Type to json (I get an exception that it can't deserialize 'model' into json, which makes sense). Note that the post body is **not** json, it's key-value pair in format: _parameterName: 'string (json) value'_

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own Custom model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext){

       // Here you can process request body, that how you want
       HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

       // Return your model
       return new CustomModel{ ... };

    }
}
```

Then you can bind this Model binder to your model in Application_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CustomModel), new CustomModelBinder());
}
```

Or you can set Model binder directly in ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult YourAction([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))] CustomModel model){
   ...
}
```